# php form action handler and save it

Tags: php

i am trying to make a page for form action handler using php

the the problem is that i want the action to be saved on that page

here's my form on index.php

```
<form method="get" onSubmit="return val()" action="han.php">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

and here's my php code on han.php

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];
echo "Your Name is:".$name;
?>
```

i need that name to be saved on han.php file like this every time i submit a name:

`Your Name is: Brian
Your Name is: Jack
Your Name is: Daniel
Your Name is: Bob`

Comment: what do you mean by "save" ... do you want to save every name, is entered, or one name and call the person by this name (like login formular)?

Comment: Use a session variable.

Comment: @JarlikStepsto dear what i mean by save is , when i go to form and submit a name and that name must be saved on han.php file and so on for ever name i submit

Comment: @Barmar how do i use seson variable bro can you please post an answer and show me ?

Comment: U can't save forever names in php file. If u save in session when u close browser all will gone, so better to save that in database or file and then call it from database or file in that han.php script.

Comment: Do you want all users to see the name of the last user who sent the form? Or should each user just see their own name? Maybe you should be using a cookie if you want it to persist after the current session.

Comment: There are lots of tutorials on using session variables and cookies in PHP. I'm not going to try to teach you here.

Comment: @Barmar no it's alowed for all users

Comment: So when I submit the form I should see the list of all names before me?

Comment: yes see Amr is answer @Barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to create another file for saved names for example **names.txt** then in your **han.php** you could write this to save the name each time the form is submitted:

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];
$file = fopen("names.txt","a");
echo fwrite($file,"$name, \n");
fclose($file);
return header('Location: index.php'); // to redirect to index.php page
?>
```

Comment: here this is what i needed bro

Comment: butthe problem is it's not saving name like a list

Comment: You should use `"a"` instead of `"w"` to append to the file instead of overwriting.

Comment: instead of `echo fwrite($file,"$name, \n");` do this `echo fwrite($file,"- $name \n");` and it will be like a list.

Comment: You can also do it in just one line using `file_put_contents("filename", "$name, \n", FILE_APPEND);`

Comment: Amr and @Barmar but is that possible to save it on php file instead of txt ?

Comment: i think that is dum question :D

Comment: what if that file names.txt wasn't exist will it be created automacially ? @Barmar

Comment: @MmPp You shouldn't be modifying PHP files like this. Save it in a txt file and the PHP file should read the file.

Comment: @MmPp Yes, it will be.

Comment: Can't you read the documentation to answer such a basic question?

Comment: oh wait there's a problem @AmrAly why when i submittd a name i get random numbers showing instead of name ?

Comment: @MmPp i have modified the answer to be redirected back after submitting the form.

Comment: @AmrAly bro please check my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42626335/php-form-not-working-correctly-when-action-added-to-the-form

Answer (score 0):

You can save them in the current session

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['names']))
  $_SESSION['names'] = array();

if(isset($_GET['name']))
  array_push($_SESSION['names'], $_GET['name']);

if(isset($_SESSION['names']))
    foreach($_SESSION['names'] as $name)
        echo $name."<br>";
?>
```

Comment: and that saves the name on han.php file ?

Comment: You can't append the names to the actual file. But whenever you call  han.php, it will show you the names on the browser.

Comment: please check Amr is answer that is what i needed

Answer (score 0):

It is not fully clear, what you mean by save, but here are some possible solutions:

**1. Every name schould be saved "for ever" (big amount of names expected):**

Use a Database like MySQL ([see here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp))

**2. The current name should be saved for a period of time:**

Use session variables for this case

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['name']) {
    $_SESSION['name'] = $_GET['name'];
    $_SESSION['name'] = date();
}
```

you can also check befor this, if a period of time has expired and overwrite the name variable.

**3. One or more names should be saved for all calls of the script (from any user):**

You can use a file and save the names in this file:

[create and write to file](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_create.asp)

[read from file](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_open.asp) OR [get whole file (file_get_contents)](http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: please check AMR is answer that is what i needed it must be save on a file